# Creating Activity from a service

Tags: android, android-intent, service, android-activity, android-pendingintent

I have activities A, B, C, D and a service S.
Hierarchy of the activities is A->B->C->D

When the service gets a signal, the service add a notification and when a user click it, I want to create a new activity E.
If there is an existing task, create the activity as a children of bottom-most activity.
(i.e A->B->C->E or A->E or A->B->E or A->B->C->D->E)
in this case, A, B, C, D have to be the same state as before and E is a new activity.
If there is no existing task (no running task), create the activity under another new activity A.
(i.e A->E)
in this case, A, E are all new activities.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Without the flow of A-E its hard to say. Can you explain what exactly you're trying to do? There may be a better way to do this.

Comment: Hm.. I'm just developing a simple chat app, and what Im trying to do is that if the app is not running, I want to open a chat activity with main activity as its parent (meaning pressing back goes to the main activity). and if the app is running, I want to open a chat activity as the top activity of the running task (keeping all the state of existing activities). Let's say A is Main activity, B is Settings activity, C is User Settings activity, D is User name change activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my understanding if you have

```
A -> B -> C -> D -> E
```

Then this means that when going back from E you end up in D and then C etc. Otherwise your statement of what you assume is **wrong**.

Basically what you *COULD* do instead of doing A-E is just go straight to E and pass in the data that will lead to that respective conversation by packing this into your notification's data.

There is no need to go A-E if you can just go to E and if the user goes back with the back button, you should be intercepting it and handling the flow to respect your design. Doing this should always go from E-A in steps. Otherwise you implemented the flow of your application in a poor fashion.

Also your setup of how A-D is **poor design**. You **should** change this to reflect what I described.

### An example

```
Main screen (A)

List Screen (B)

Message Screen (C)

Details Screen (D)
```

This makes sense and is a better flow. To go straight to D and then traverse backwards from D to A using the Back button.

### Note

Any setting screens **SHOULD NOT** be in the flow as this is confusing for the user as they did not traverse through it so its a *contextless* screen to display. And your service should not be a part of the flow either, it's state should be maintained by the activity as necessary.

Comment: just go straight to E and pass in the data that will lead to that respective conversation by packing this into your notification's data. Do you mean by creating pendingintent with taskstackbuilder?

Comment: taskstackbuilder...? I have no idea what this is.. but your notification should be directly linking to a certain message. And lead to that particular screen in my example D screen.

Comment: In my code, when a user click the notification, pendingintent would be sent. and that pendingintent don't build the activity hierarchy again. If i start activity D by clicking notification, it will show me D activity and traversing back will move to the home screen.

Comment: This means you are not intercepting the back button to respect your flow. Fix that, by current standard this is bad design you should consider asserting more control of your application's activities and their flow.

Comment: I got my plan and it works by sending a broadcasting PendingIntent  with the notification.